# Character length filter

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

On Math Stack Exchange, you can create a custom filter. That gave me an idea for a feature to add to the filter, and that is the ability to sort by character ranges. You could put in the filter "Give questions ranging from $50-100$ characters" and get very short questions. This is because there are a lot of questions that aren't suitable for this site where the author just put the question down, so the question would obviously be very short. Thus, by adding this filter it will be very easy to locate these types of questions and flag them.

Example questions (edit more in if you have them):

[Maxima And Minima At The Critical Points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291863/maxima-and-minima-at-the-critical-points)

[Difficult text task - beverage crates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076144/difficult-text-task-beverage-crates)

[principal ideal notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233214/principal-ideal-notation)

[Find all x,y and z such that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076261/find-all-x-y-and-z-such-that)

Comment: I want to ask you, just because of the quantity of posts, most already answered on this site, you post to meta, in a relatively short period of time:  do you spend a lot of time pondering what you can ask on meta that might not yet be addressed?  Do you spend time searching for duplicate questions before scratching the itch to ask on meta?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I agree for the most part with your hypothesis, that short character length of questions correlate positively with poor questions/PSQs.   But there are exceptions.  I prefer for users, though, to flag or vote to close or upvote posts as they appear on this site, based on their quality. E.g., searching for posts one user posted as questions, because you've noticed a few low quality questions, and then going through them to downvote other poor quality questions crosses the line into targeting users.

Comment: Please avoid excessively moderating old content. Not saying that it shouldn't be dealt with, in principle. But there is **a lot more than enough** fresh content dumped on the site every single day that requires a higher priority of attention. If you want to help, do *that*.

Comment: This reminded me of [Alexander Gruber's project](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/107936/2020/5/13) - he wants to create something similar to SmokeDetector, but for catching possibly problematic posts (crank questions, frequent duplicates, PSQs). One of the criteria might be length.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than having to find them yourself, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this if you know a bit of SQL. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1390200/shortest-questions?numberOfHits=100) is such a query listing the shortest questions (measured by body length) on the site.

Do note that there are times where short questions are good and more text would just be extraneous. Also, flagging very old questions isn't necessarily the most productive cleanup task on the site.

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the most recent questions aren't in there yet.

Comment: I appreciate the "Do note..." and the "Also..."